How to see styling of a mui class applied to an element?
I use material ui components as part of a react project.
After the code is loaded onto the browser, I see 3 classes applied to the <p> tag element that I am looking at. I also applied some inline styling to that element. How I do see the styling wrt 2 classes that material ui applied to that element ?

I am specifically talking about cme-web-MuiTypography-body1 and cme-web-MuiTypography-root classes in this situation. I cant see the styles for them in this Styles pane. Just the way I can see the styling for css-5woiax-MuiTypography-root. I want see for the other ones too.
